# "while" not working inside "for" (completely ignored)

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, for-in-loop

Basically, when I enter the temperature and if the value was more 60 and less than 0, it should say that the code is invalid and please type it again, until it gets a value between 1 and 59. But for my code, the while loop is like completely ignored... Why is that?

```
# TASK 1:
midDayTemp = float()
midNightTemp = float()
midDayList = []
midNightList = []

for day in range (3):
    print ("Day:", day + 1)
    midDayTemp = float(input("Please enter your Mid-Day temperature\n"))


    while midDayTemp >= 60 and midDayTemp <= 0:
         midDayTemp = input("Invalid, please re-enter your temperature\n")

    midDayList.append(midDayTemp)

    midNightTemp = float(input("Please enter your Mid-Night temperature\n"))


    while midNightTemp >= 60 and midNightTemp <= 0:
         midNightTemp = input("Invalid, please re-enter your temperature\n")

    midNightList.append(midNightTemp)
# TASK 2:
print("Mid-Day readings are ",midDayList)
midDayAverage = sum(midDayList) / len(midDayList)
print ("The average is ", midDayAverage)
print("Mid-Night readings are ",midNightList)
midNightAverage = sum(midNightList) / len(midNightList)
print ("The average is ", midNightAverage)


# TASK 3:
minValueMidDay = min(midDayList)
print ("The lowest temperature of the Mid-Day is", minValueMidDay )
maxValueMidDay = max(midDayList)
print ("The highest temperature of the Mid-Day is", maxValueMidDay )
minValueMidNight = min(midNightList)
print ("The lowest temperature of the Mid-Night is", minValueMidNight )
maxValueMidNight = max(midNightList)
print ("The highest temperature of the Mid-Night is", maxValueMidNight )

print ("Thank you for using my code!")
```

Thank you

Comment: Read this `midNightTemp >= 60 and midNightTemp <= 0`, what number could possibly satisfy that condition? Hint: not possible, you likely meant `or`

Comment: `midDayTemp >= 60 and midDayTemp <= 0:` will never be true. An integer cannot be greater than 60 and less that 0 at the same  time

Comment: yup, your comparison is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Just to notify that such condition in Python can be chained like `0 <= midDayTemp <= 60`

Comment: replace and with or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is no number that is both greater than or equal to 60 and smaller or equal to zero.

You must change the and for a or.

```
while midDayTemp >= 60 or midDayTemp <= 0:
```